# Let $G$ be an abelian group s.t $H$ is a subgroup of index $n$. Prove that $\forall g \in G, g^n \in H$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group s.t $H$ is a subgroup of index $n$. Prove that $\forall g \in G, g^n \in H$.

I'm trying to split into some cases, where both cases that $ g \in H$ and case where ${\rm ord}(g)\mid n$ are clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that in any finite group $A$, $a^{|A|}$ is the identity of the group for every $a \in A$. So, since $|G/H| = n$, $(gH)^n = H$ for every $g \in G$.

Comment: could you make it explicit where do you use that the group is abelian ?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, to ensure that $H$ is normal, and then $G/H$ is a group.

Answer (score 1):

You're right both of those cases are pretty clear.  But now consider the subgroup $\langle gH\rangle$ of $G/H$ and apply Lagrange.